# Web Server/Domain setup to forward all but specific directories/files

Tags: apache, http, dns, virtualhost, httpd.conf

End goal: I’d like to create a webserver that forwards all requests, except specific directories.

For example:
`site.com -> target.com
 site.com/anything -> target.com
 site.com/anythingElse.php -> target.com`
but…
`site.com/specificPath -> site.com/specificPath
 site.com/specificFile.php -> site.com/specificFile.php`

Aside: It would be great if the server could also handle a number of domains (virtual hosts) and separate SSL certs for each of those domains.

I am happy to use web server forwarding, CNAME records, etc.. Perhaps you can help with what you think is the best practice in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method with regex called negative lookahead, it is meant for cases like this, here is a rough example in virtualhost context:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?!specificPath|specificFile.php)(.*) http://target.example.com/$1
```

editnote: If what you want is reverse proxying (you said forward but I thought you wanted to redirect externally), just let me know.